# Rate and respective integral not matching intuition of graph

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Recently, I was tasked to investigate an algorithm given the data in which the units are digits generated per second. The algorithm generates transcendental constants (i.e. e, $\pi$, $\phi$, etc.) Anyhow, I got the data and cleaning it up, I arrived at this function:

$$
B'(x) = \frac{dB}{dx} = 2510.46885(1.00851478)^{-1.06290079x}
$$

Which if you would graph it, it would look like exponential decay. To better understand this model, let me show you an example: $B'(1000) = 0.3061$ digits per second. This means when the algorithm is on digit 1000 of $\pi$ or $e$, the instantenous rate is that 0.3061 digits per second. So $B'(20000) = 0.000037$ digits per second, and it makes sense as it gets harder to generate the 20000th digit than the 1000th digit. Notice I put $B'(x)$ as it is a rate of change. Solving the differential equation involves taking the integral like so:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\displaystyle
\int dB &= \int 2510.46885(1.00851478)^{-1.06290079x} dx \\
& = 2510.46885 \int 1.00851478^{-1.06290079x} dx \\
& = \frac{2510.46885}{-1.06290079} \int 1.00851478^{-1.06290079x} d(-1.06290079x) \\
& = -2361.903268 \int 1.00851478^{-1.06290079x} d(-1.06290079x) \\
B(x) & = -2361.903268 \frac{1.00851478^{-1.06290079x}}{\ln(1.00851478)} + C \\
& = C - 278568(1.00851)^{-1.06290079x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I also happen to have an initial condition $B(1000) = 15.23$. This is different from $B'$, as now this means to generate 1000 digits, it will take 15.23 seconds. Solving for $C$:

$$
B(1000) = 15.23 = C - 278568(1.00851)^{-1.06290079(1000)} \\
15.23 = C - 278568(1.00851)^{-1062.90079} \\
15.23 = C - 34.1377 \\
C = 49.2677
$$

Then, plugging $C$ back into above:
$$
B(x) = 49.2677 - 278568(1.00851)^{-1.06290079x}
$$

Now here is where it gets murky. Looking at $B(x)$ it caps out at 49.2677. So now, I am very confused as shouldn't the integral give the total time elapsed? Because to me, a exponential graph like $e^x$ would make more sense, as the more digits you want to generate, the exponentially longer it would take. It certainly didn't take only 49.2 seconds to generate 100,000 or 1 billion digits of $\pi$. So, what happened? Did I understand the differential equation correctly? Am I wrong to assume the integral represents total time?

Comment: Probably easier to express the derivative as $B'(x) = 2510.46885\exp(-0.00901205278 x)$

Answer (score 1):

What you have calculated is the number of digits you will get if you spend $x$ time calculating. Apparently this method is going to cap out at 49 digits according to this model, so perhaps an exponential wasn't the best choice of fit.

If you want the time it takes to get $B$ digits, you need to invert that function.

Comment: Any other type of models I can fit this in? The original data looks like an L-shaped curve due to how fast the rate decreases.

Comment: @VJZ When exponential doesn't work, the next thing to try is power law. That is, $a x^p$ for some $a$ and $p$.